# How to transform a HttpResponse into a HttpErrorResponse

Tags: angular

I have a web service returning custom errors inside a `200` Response, in a *classic* `errors` object.

This breaks my workflow and patterns, where I usually intercept proper HTTP error status codes and go on with handling the various error cases from there.

I need to transform these custom errors into proper `HttpErrorResponse` errors via an interceptor, so that I can then intercept those now-proper errors and continue with my application per usual best practices.

### Things I can't do:

- Have the web service modified so that it returns proper HTTP errors
- Have another web service in the middle to handle the transformation before the Response hits the client application

### What I'd like to do:

- Make the following Stackblitz example work. The part that needs to be fixed is in `interceptors/custom-error.interceptor.ts`
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pnv63p

So that when in the near future I'll be working on several other applications that use the same unmodifiable web service, I can just drop the `CustomErrorInterceptor` in and call it a day.

Comment: And here's the answer a buddy of mine just found:

`throw new HttpErrorResponse({ error: 'bar', status: 403 });`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

And here's the answer a buddy of mine just found:

`throw new HttpErrorResponse({ error: 'bar', status: 403 });`

Comment: add that if you want to return an error stream that will be caught by catchError() you have to use:

`return throwError(new HttpErrorResponse({ error: 'bar', status: 403 }));`